# Tomcat can't find JSF API in a JSF webapp built by Maven with javaee-api dependency

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jsf-2

I have searched many similar posts, however I cannot find a definitive answer on the correct way to build and deploy JSF applications, therefore I'm hoping someone can help...

Currently I am using Eclipse with Maven to build a simple JSF application and deploy it onto Tomcat 7, with one dependency in the POM.xml of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupid>javax</groupid>
    <artifactid>javaee-api</artifactid>
    <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I deploy onto the server I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
```

I cant figure out where this is coming from? I have no listeners defined in web.xml.

If I then change my dependency to:

```
<dependency>
    <groupid>javax</groupid>
    <artifactid>javaee-api</artifactid>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</provided>
</dependency>
```

And attempt to run the application on the server I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
```

Which I can understand because I am now using scope as provided and thus it expects Tomcat to have the implementation and it cannot find it.

Finally if I drop javax.faces.2.1.13.jar into tomcat install dir/lib folder it works fine.

The javaee-api-6.0.jar imported using the Maven dependencies seems to contain the same javax.faces.* classes as the javax.faces.2.1.13.jar, therefore can anyone tell me why this doesn't work when I try and run the application on the server without scope as provided?

Although it works when having the javax.faces.2.1.13.jar in the tomcat install dir/lib folder, is this the correct way to deploy a faces application?

Comment: What happens if you just omit the javaee-api dependency and add the faces dependency to your pom? I don't think you have to take care about including the javaee-api dependency..

Comment: Tomcat is not a Java EE container. It's a barebones JSP/Servlet container. It has only JSP, Servlet and EL APIs, not the remainder as available by Java EE (JSF, JPA, EJB, JMS, CDI, etc, etc, etc). Your Maven configuration will work on real Java EE containers (Glassfish, JBoss, WebSphere, etc).

Comment: @XtremeBiker - If I provide jsf-api and jsf-impl from com.sun.faces then it will work without me having to provide the javaee-api dependency or have the javax.faces.version.jar in my tomcat install/lib folder, so I think you are spot on about not needing the javaee-api dependency.

Comment: @BalusC - Thanks, I wasn't aware that Tomcat wasn't a full Java EE container. Architecturally, I guess its best to set the scope as provided for any required JSF jars within Maven and then deploy to a full Java EE container.